# Flyout or Popup to display addition info

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-10, uwp

I want display popup on top my app with additional information, my info is `Listview` with ~500 items I've tried both:

- problem with `flyout` -> it has probably scrollViewer inside so my listview doesn't Virtualize correctly everything else is ok. There is my code:

  ```
  Flyout myFlyout = new Flyout();
  myFlyout.Placement = FlyoutPlacementMode.Full;
  myFlyout.Content = myListView;
  myFlyout.ShowAt(this);
  ```
- problem with `popup` -> it isn't centered, verticalAlignment doesn't work, horizontal neither

  ```
  Popup myPopup = new Popup();
  myPopup.Child = myListView;
  myPopup.IsOpen = true;
  ```

So which way should I go, try to edit Template of flyout or center my popup by setting vertical and horizontal offset?
Or there's better way to display popup like window with info like list of items or such other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `Flyout` has a `ScrollViewer` inside. You can find its template at [FlyoutPresenter styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt299125.aspx). You can edit it and use new template by setting [Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout.flyoutpresenterstyle.aspx) property if you need.

If you want to use `Popup`'s `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` property, you need add `Popup` as a child of an element in the visual tree. For example:

```
Popup myPopup = new Popup();
//MainGrid is the top Grid in the Page
MainGrid.Children.Add(myPopup);
myPopup.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
myPopup.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
myPopup.Child = myListView;
myPopup.IsOpen = true;
```

But plesae note that this actually dose not make the `Popup` centered. It make the `Popup`'s upper left corner centered. In the **Remarks** section of [Popup class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup.aspx), it says:

> You position the **Popup** by setting the [HorizontalOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup.horizontaloffset) and [VerticalOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup.verticaloffset) properties. The **Popup** is offset relative to its immediate parent container.

I think while using `HorizontalAlignment.Center` and `VerticalAlignment.Center`, it set the `HorizontalOffset` and `VerticalOffset` to the half of its parent's width and height.

And in the **Remarks** section, it also says:

> Do not use a **Popup** if a [Flyout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout.aspx), [MenuFlyout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyout.aspx), [ToolTip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.tooltip.aspx) or [MessageDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog.aspx) is more appropriate.

So I think in your case using `Flyout` is a better way.