# How do I make a UWP Popup associated with a control programatically?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

A behavior I am writing needs to associate a popup with a control - so that the position of the popup is always relative to that control.

In UWP, Popups do not have the placement property to play with. How do I then associate it with a control? (I know I can manually calculate the position, but that gets very complicated very quickly when you realize that resizing the window does not necesserily affect the control, and so it becomes very hard to know when to update the positon)

I cannot use flyouts because I need a popup that's not light-dismissable.

Comment: can you show us some code? it will help us understand

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641460/flyout-or-popup-to-display-addition-info

Comment: @DanZ: Thanks! Not really.. Notice that they know the top-level control they want to programatically associate the popup with and then they just add it as a child. I need to do this for any control (like Flyout knows how to do)

Comment: Bind the control to one property.  Then bind the placement of the popup to another property that dynamically calculates it based on the current window size and the control's position. If someone resizes the window while the popup is open I think it will close anyway with light dismiss.

Comment: @SeanO'Neil
I dont want light dismiss (that's why I can't use Flyout). There's no placement property on popup - otherwise I would not have had an issue. Or do you mean something else by placement?

Comment: I mean vertical and horizontal offset. Popups have light dismiss as an option which is the only use for them I've ever had. Since you don't want light dismiss why not just hide and show a Grid? You could even put the Grid and the Control in a RelativePanel.  There are quite a few ways you could achieve this.

Comment: @SeanO'Neil: There are a ton of non-light dismiss popups - for example, that thing that appears under text boxes with auto complete? That's a popup. If you dont make it a popup, it becomes much harder to handle z-order or "go outside" your control bounderies. Popup is actually THE way you are supposed to do that, it's just that generally popups are children of XAML controls and in my case this is a dynamic behavior you can attach.

Comment: Well if we’re talking about the way you’re supposed to do things popups aren’t meant to be positioned relative to a control, that’s what RelativePanels are for.  There’s many ways to achieve what you’re doing, if you go with popup then vertical and horizontal offset are the properties you’re looking for.

Comment: @SeanO'Neil: Popups are most certainly used this way. All over WPF in Microsoft implemented controls. That's why you can make a popup a child of another control.

Comment: I'm not talking about parent containers obviously. A popup's default position is the top-left corner of its parent container.  Vertical/Horizontal offset is used to repositioni it. This is a pointless discussion, it seems like you don't actually have a question and you're just complaining that the UWP popup doesn't have the Placement property the WPF one does. UWP is not WPF. Unlike WPF, UWP does have RelativePanel which is what you use when you want a control to dynamically be positioned based on the position of a sibling control. You can set ZIndex to 99999.

Comment: @SeanO'Neil: Thanks for the answer. Again - I cannot use RelativePanel because that's a flow control that's part of the page. Since what I am wrtiting is a behavior, I do not want to modify the XAML I am on , and so my only option is to find a way to associate the control (if it exists, it seems like it does not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I make a UWP Popup associated with a control programatically?

If you mean associate two controls code behind, I think the [`ExpressionAnimation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Composition.ExpressionAnimation) is what you want.

Properties of the `Popup` control visual could be calculated based on another control by `Expression` you defined. Just for simple example, the following code snippet makes the `Popup` always has `Offset.X` to `50` based on another visual's `Offset`.

```
private void btnmain_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _visualA.Offset = new System.Numerics.Vector3(400, 350, 350);
}

private void btntest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _visualA = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(btnmain);
    _visualB = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(pop); 
    compositor = _visualB.Compositor; 
    var expression = compositor.CreateExpressionAnimation("visualA.Offset.X + 50");
    expression.SetReferenceParameter("visualA", _visualA);
    _visualB.StartAnimation("Offset.X", expression);
}
```

For detail calculation please do it yourself based on your scenarios.More details please reference [WindowsUIDevLabs](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs).

Comment: This is a great approach. Will try it this week. Thanks Sunteen. Marking as answer for now.